# Guzzle async method is not firing HTTP request asynchronously

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I have a slow slow function that takes about 20s to run and a HTTP request takes 3.4s to run.

I want to:

1. Fire off an async HTTP request (should be almost 0s, as I am not waiting for a response)
2. Then run a slow function (~20s)
3. Then get the result of the HTTP request at the end. (should be almost 0s, as I should have received the response by now, as the HTTP request was being done asynchronously)

If the HTTP request is done asynchronously, step 1 & 3 should be done in almost no time at all.

I used the following code:

```
$client = new Client();

$promise = $client->getAsync('http://www.fakeresponse.com/api/?sleep=3')->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res) {
        return \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
);

// Slow function
$start = microtime(true);
$this->slowFunction(); // ~20s
dump($end); 

$start = microtime(true);
$promise->wait();
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
dump($end); // Should be 0 if running async
```

Which outputted:

```
19.018649101257
3.3757498264313
```

This means step 3 took ~3.4s to run, meaning `->getAsync` is not firing off the HTTP request. It's instead firing it off on `->wait`.

How do I get the HTTP request to fire asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pthreads.php) lib to fire something asynchronous with php, as an example of use :

```
<?php

class MyThread extends Thread{
    public $promise;
    public $terminated;
    public function __construct($promise) {
        $this->terminated=false;
        $this->promise=$promise;
    }
    public function run(){
        $this->promise->wait();
        $this->terminated=true;
    }
}



$client = new Client();

$promise = $client->getAsync('https://www.foaas.com/version')->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res) {
        return \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
);

$start = microtime(true);
print $start;
$thread = new MyThread($promise);
while(!$thread->terminated){
    usleep(1);
}
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
print " - ".$end;
```